# Stop div container from resizing

Tags: html, css, resize

I have two columns in an html page, one is floated right and the other is floated left.
I have set the height of both containers to 100% and the width of both containers to 50%.  I want the two containers to fit the entre window.  When the user re-sizes the window horizontally I don't want the content to resize.  How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: When you use percentage widths, the content will resize to fill the screen. If you don't want the resize to happen, don't use percentage widths. Instead, consider using Javascript to calculate the screen size when the page loads initially, and retain those values in your CSS even after a page resize even occurs.

Comment: You want you content be centered when the browser get larger and get a scroll when browser get smaller?

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You want the content to fit the entire window, but you don't want it to resize on window resize?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is many way to achieve that. First of all, the easiest would be to put the css value min-width! So if you want it to resize but to stop at 960px (for example) you just have to do :

```
    myCoolDiv{
         width: 100%;
         height: 50%;
         min-width: 960px;
   }
```

That would give you the best result. Else, if you dont want content to resize at all, and the selector to have a width equal to 100% of the initial screen, I would use jQuery that way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       //Call a variable to know the width of the window
       var screenWidth = $(window).width();
       $('myCoolDiv').css('width', screenWidth + 'px');
    });
```

Hope it helped! Tell me if my answer is not clear enough or if you don't understand a part of it!

Cheers!

Comment: You said , there are many ways , can you tell us ,what are other way to achieve this

Comment: @rajeevpani.. min-width or min-height really is the way to go here, other methods could be used depending on the problem but I'd say that if you want container to resize but have a limit to the resize, you want min-width or max-width to be implied. I'm not sure what I had in mind at the time but I was probably thinking about CSS media query and such, but now that I read the problem again I'd say that the answer is the best way to go.

Comment: No need for JS, just use `width: 100vw`/`height: 100vh` (viewport-width and viewport-height units respectively).