# make a div stop after reaching some point on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the div "box" stop moving along the screen and stay just after reaching the end of the div "banner":

[image]

How is that possible? Also would really appreciate if you note any mistakes in my code.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.banner').hide().slideDown(800);
  $('.banner h1').hide().show().addClass('animateText')
  $('.box').hide()
  var $win = $(window);

  $win.on("scroll", function () {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();
    $('.banner h1').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + top + 'deg)'})

    if (top > 150){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':0})
      $('.banner p').slideDown(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': top*1.2 + 'px'})
      $('.box').slideDown(600)
      $('.box').css({'transform': 'translateY(' + top/2 + 'px)'})
      
    } else if(top < 400){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':1})
      $('.banner p').slideUp(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': '-400px', 'transition':'600ms'})
      $('.box').slideUp(1000);
      
    } 
    
    //kinda like this:
    if(top>$('.banner').outerHeight()){
      $('.box').stopRightWhereYouAre()
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.banner{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.animateText{
  animation: slide 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    margin-left: -800px
  }
  50%{
    font-size: 350px;
  }
  100%{
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner p{
  color:white;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -17%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color:black;
  top:250px;
  left:-400px;
  position: absolute;

}

.box{
  background-color: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.h{
  margin-bottom: 300vh
}

.box p{
  color:white;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <div class="rotate"><h2>DESIGN</h2></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788192/stop-div-container-from-resizing

Comment: Couldn't figure..

Comment: @valeria apply position: absolute or fixed to the `box` div

Comment: @valeria you are speaking about the second black box if I am not mistaken you want it to not pass the first black box (stop under the first box)

Comment: yes yes exactly

Comment: @valeria check this http://jsfiddle.net/ar4qs5xw/4/ before I post the answer

Comment: well.. not quite. i want it to do the whole translateY on scroll thing (like it is now) and then stop after the first div, like you did now

Comment: @valeria and now http://jsfiddle.net/ar4qs5xw/5/

Comment: oh wow its even better! thank you. now i get the idea..lol

Comment: @valeria I will post the code as an answer mark it as the right one

Comment: you should look up for the CSS value of `position: sticky`, i'm sure you can acomplish this without any javascript ^^

Comment: ikrr!! ive tried that a million times already haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.banner').hide().slideDown(800);
  $('.banner h1').hide().show().addClass('animateText')
  $('.box').hide()
  var $win = $(window);

  $win.on("scroll", function () {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();
    $('.banner h1').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + top + 'deg)'})

    if (top > 150 && top<$('.banner').outerHeight()){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':0})
      $('.banner p').slideDown(800);
      var lf = top*1.2 < (window.innerWidth - $('.banner')[0].offsetWidth) ? top*1.2 : (window.innerWidth - $('.banner')[0].offsetWidth);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': lf + 'px'})
      $('.box').slideDown(600);
      var ty = ($('.banner')[0].offsetHeight - top*1.2) <= 0 ? 0 : ($('.banner')[0].offsetHeight - top*1.2)
      $('.box').css({'transform': 'translateY(' + ty + 'px)'})
      
    } else if(top < 400 && top<$('.banner').outerHeight()){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':1})
      $('.banner p').slideUp(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': '-400px', 'transition':'600ms'})
      $('.box').slideUp(1000);
      
    } 

  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.banner{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.animateText{
  animation: slide 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    margin-left: -800px
  }
  50%{
    font-size: 350px;
  }
  100%{
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner p{
  color:white;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -17%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color:black;
  top:250px;
  left:-400px;
  position: absolute;

}

.box{
  background-color: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40%;
  /*margin-top: -400px;*/
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.h{
  margin-bottom: 300vh
}

.box p{
  color:white;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <div class="rotate"><h2>DESIGN</h2></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: @valeria it's the same as `$('.banner').outerHeight()` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079032/what-is-the-jquery-equivalent-to-offsetheight as for `[0]` it get the first element that have the class `banner`